# Set Spring Integration header value to bean property

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Is there anyway to set value of spring integration  header to bean property.

```
<int:header-enricher>
  <int:header name="bId" expression="T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID()" />
</int:header-enricher>
```

Now in bean definition

```
<bean id="" class="">
    <property name="bId" value="#{headers['bId']}" />
</bean>
```

This above code doesn't work. this throws exception

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on object of type 'org.spri
ngframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
```

I tried below ways, they don't work

```
<bean id="" class="">
    <property name="bId" value="headers['bId']" />
</bean>

<bean id="" class="">
    <property name="bId" ref="headers['bId']" />
</bean>
```

Below would've been ideal, but this `expression` is not available

```
<bean id="" class="">
    <property name="bId" expression="headers['bId']" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Integration expressions such as

```
<int:header name="bId" expression="T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID()" />
```

are **runtime** expressions - they apply to messages flowing through the system; in most cases the root object for the expression evaluation is the `Message`.

Expressions such as

```
<property name="bId" value="#{...}" />
```

are **initialization** time SpEL expressions - they are evaluated during context initialization. There is no `Message` object yet - the root object for the evaluation is the application context, so you can do things like referencing properties on other beans

```
 <property name="bId" value="#{somebean.foo}" />
```

There's a big difference between these types of expressions.