# Set spring integration header into soap header in spring integration (without interceptor/ threadlocal)

Tags: spring, soap, spring-integration, spring-ws

Is there anyway to set SOAP-ENV header in spring integration xml from spring integration headers ?

I tried below approach and expected `bId` to be populated to soap headers

```
<int:chain id="soapcall" input-channel="soapchannel">      
        <int-xml:header-enricher>
            <int-xml:header name="bId" expression="headers['bId']"/>
        </int-xml:header-enricher>
          <int-ws:outbound-gateway  uri="${soap.url}" interceptor="myInterceptor">
          </int-ws:outbound-gateway> 
     </int:chain>
```

However Actual output doesn't have the header. see below:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:n1="http://namespace/n1">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body> ...
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I also looked into below approach inside chain before calling outbound gateway. It seems this header enricher takes only soap action as header. So this throws exception `action headers not found`

```
<int-ws:header-enricher >
            <int-ws:soap-action expression="headers['bId']"/>
          </int-ws:header-enricher>
```

I also looked into [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/128136-how-to-return-soap-header-with-custom-properties-from-inbound-gateway?p=611562#post611562) post. But I couldn't get this compiled inside a chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the `<int-xml:header-enricher>`, but it doesn't matter.

What you need is called `header-mapper` on the `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>`.

Its code looks like:

```
@Override
protected void populateStandardHeaders(Map<String, Object> headers, SoapMessage target) {
    String soapAction = getHeaderIfAvailable(headers, WebServiceHeaders.SOAP_ACTION, String.class);
    if (!StringUtils.hasText(soapAction)) {
        soapAction = "\"\"";
    }
    target.setSoapAction(soapAction);
}

@Override
protected void populateUserDefinedHeader(String headerName, Object headerValue, SoapMessage target) {
    SoapHeader soapHeader = target.getSoapHeader();
    if (headerValue instanceof String) {
        QName qname = QNameUtils.parseQNameString(headerName);
        soapHeader.addAttribute(qname, (String) headerValue);
    }
}
```

So, by default it maps `WebServiceHeaders.SOAP_ACTION` as a standard one, and all those user defined if they are `String` and only as `attribute` of the target `SOAP-ENV:Header` element.

Those user defined headers can be mapped by the:

```
<xsd:attribute name="mapped-request-headers" type="xsd:string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
Comma-separated list of names of SOAP Headers to be mapped from the SOAP request into the MessageHeaders.
This can only be provided if the 'header-mapper' reference is not being set directly. The values in
this list can also be simple patterns to be matched against the header names (e.g. "foo*" or "*foo").
                        ]]></xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
```

If you need to populate sub-elements to the `<SOAP-ENV:Header>`, you don't have choice unless extend `DefaultSoapHeaderMapper` and override that `populateUserDefinedHeader()` and use `SoapHeader.addHeaderElement()` API.

Also look into the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ws.html#ws-message-headers).

Comment: Basically I want to get value of spring integration header inside the  interceptor. I am trying different approaches to achieve that. See my [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382580/pass-parameter-to-spring-soap-interceptor/39391241#39391241)

Comment: ??? Your question is "without interceptor". OTOH it isn't interceptor responsibility to modify message. The interceptor is part of SOAP already. It is normal that there is nothing about Spring Integration

Comment: I am trying to log soap request envelope inside interceptor. headers[bId] in the spring message, is database column, used to associate each soap request to corresponding database id. but interceptor doesn't give access to spring integration message header. so trying work around here by adding bId to soap headers

Comment: Ok. So, I think the suggested solution with the simple `mapped-request-headers` and further extraction in the interceptor should be enough for you .

Comment: I've been trying with `mapped-request-headers` for all day. Not sure what I missed earlier. Worked now. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Glad to be helpful!

Comment: @ViratKohli Can you give the sample implementation how you achieved it. I am not able to make it.